# Использование пути для подключения картнок в Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, yii

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть тестовый проект на Yii 2. Там подключение картинок идёт таким образом:

```
Html::img('@web/web/img/img_1.jpg')
<img src="/web/img/img_2.png" />
```

Могу ли я их подключать без "web"? Т.е., вот так:

```
Html::img('@web/img/img_1.jpg')
<img src="/img/img_2.png" />
```

Может быть .htaccess как-нибудь поможет? Спасибо!

Comment: Какая у вас файловая структура? Возможно вам необходимо переопределить корневую директорию проекта.

Comment: Файловая структура там стандартная для Yii basic. Я там ни чего не менял.

    assets
    commands
    components
    config
    controllers
    mail
    models
    runtime
    tests
    vendor
    views
    web

    И уже в папке web так:
    assets
    css
    fonts
    img
    js

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать так: `$img_path = '@web/web/img/'`. А потом юзать так: `HTML::img($img_path + 'img_1.jpg')`. Попробуйте этот вариант, если не получится - поищу другие пути решения вашей задачи.

Comment: Нет, Вы меня не поняли. Вот, например, есть такая штука, как ЧПУ. Изначально, при разработке, ссылки имеют вид: view.php?id=1&name=super_vasya и т.д.... А можно сделать, например, так: view/super_vasya... Таким же образом, я бы хотел убрать из адреса отображение папки web в ссылках на изображения. Не <img src="/web/img/img_2.png" />, а <img src="/img/img_2.png" />. Но по факту папка web должна остаться.

Comment: В .htaccess я писал для css, js, img так: RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L], RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L], RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]. Может здесь нужно как-то переписать инструкцию для директив?

Comment: @Lex_1992 У вас в конфиге Apache скорее всего Web Root не стоит папка `web`. Т.е. Apache должен считать корнем папку `web`, а не корень проекта.

Comment: ОК. А как же это тогда исправить?

Comment: @LexXy на данный момент сайт на локале или на хостинге? Какое окружение используете?

Comment: На локалке. Использую OpenServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала в **OpenServer** заходим в `Настройки` вкладка `Домены` там будет выпадающий список `Управление доменами` нужно выбрать `Ручное + автопоиск`, в поле `автопоиск корневой папки домена` должно быть написано:

```
public_html www\htdocs www http htdocs docs web httpdocs public html site
```

Таким образом корнем будет не папка с проектом, а папка в проекте из этого списка, в **Yii2** это папка `web` (она есть в этом списке).

Файл `.htaccess` должен находиться в папке `web` с следующим содержанием:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Этого должно быть достаточно, на всякий случай  пример настройки `UrlManager`:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // "красивые" url (ЧПУ)
        'showScriptName' => false, // не показывать index.php в url
        'rules' => [
            // тут UrlRules
        ],
    ],
```

P.S. Когда будете размещать проект в настройках **apache** так же необходимо прописывать путь до папки `web`